# How do I create an instance variable in rails using OpenStruct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I would like to return facets along with the data in my controller. My code was :

```
def index
   @people = Person.for_branch(session[:branch_id]).for_interests(params[:interest_search]).search_query(params[:search_term]).for_lead_sources(params[:lead_source_search]).page params[:page]
   @organization = Organization.find(session[:organization_id])
   @facets.total_count = Person.all.count
   @facets.filtered_count = @people.count
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json {render partial: 'table.html', locals: { people: @people, organization: @organization, facets: @facets}}
   end
end
```

However, I keep getting the error total_count is not defined.

```
undefined method `total_count=' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I fixed this?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question with such few data.

Comment: What is `@facets` here? and what is the exact error you got?

Comment: Apologies. I have elaborated further in the question now.

Comment: where `@facets` is coming from?, which controller is this?

Comment: This is the People Controller. I just created it on line 4 of this code. Maybe this was what I am doing wrong?

Comment: there is no `@facets` variable is present in here that's why it is saying `for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how exactly do I define this variable so that it is present?

Comment: Just like other instance variables, with assignment (usually): `@facets = ...`.

Comment: Can you show us `facet` model and the `form` from where you are coming to `index action`

Comment: There is no facet model, I just want to return the data of the count of certain items along with the result. Maybe making a new instance variable for it isn't the best idea?

Comment: so you can say something like this `@facets_total_count = Person.all.count` or  `@facets_total_count = Person.count(:all)` & `@facets_filtered_count = @people.count`

Comment: Ahh yes, that worked. But I just want to have too many local variables running around

Comment: then you can create `@facets_total_count` as array with `[Person.count(:all), @people.count]` or as hash and `total_count` and `filtered_count` as keys with resp values

Comment: I think that's a good idea, I will do just that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) variable.

```
require 'ostruct'
# ...

def index
  @people = Person.for_branch(session[:branch_id]).for_interests(params[:interest_search]).search_query(params[:search_term]).for_lead_sources(params[:lead_source_search]).page params[:page]
  @organization = Organization.find(session[:organization_id])

  @facets = OpenStruct.new # initializing OpenStruct instance
  @facets.total_count = Person.all.count
  @facets.filtered_count = @people.count
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json {render partial: 'table.html', locals: { people: @people, organization: @organization, facets: @facets}}
  end
end
```

Please note, that it is more convinient to use plain old [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html) instead:

```
facets = {total_count: Person.all.count, filtered_count: @people.count}
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json {render partial: 'table.html', locals: { people: @people, organization: @organization, facets: facets}}
end
```

and use it in your views like this:

```
total count is <%= facets[:total_count] %>
```